# Write a query in MSSQL to get report for last 30 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a report basis on,

| Lead Name | Verified By | Verified on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lead 1 | ABC | 11-02-2021 |
| Lead 2 | KMJ | 9-02-2021 |
| Lead 3 | ABC | 11-02-2021 |

The report will look like,
Consider today's date as **12-02-2021**, we need to create a report for the last 30 days for employees work count

| user | 12-02-2021 | 11-02-2021 | 10-02-2021 | 9-02-2021 | 8-02-2021 | 7-02-2021 | so on till last 30 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| XYZ | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| KMJ | 0 | 0 | 0 | **1** | 0 | 0 |  |

I have written MSSQL Query as below,
`CAST(lead.CREATED_ON as date) between cast(DATEADD(day, -30, getdate()) as date) and CAST(getdate() as date)`
but, I am not able to get data in the below format, and also if there no entry for one date that date should show 0 in front of all users

| user | 12-02-2021 | 11-02-2021 | 10-02-2021 | 9-02-2021 | 8-02-2021 | 7-02-2021 | so on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Kindly help me to complete this query, if possible kindly share any article link, it will be a great help for me thank you

Comment: What you want is a dynamic pivot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are the dates *really* stored as strings like that? If so, that's a big problem that will make this already-difficult situation much worse. It's important enough you should consider the current schema as actively **broken**.

Moving on, the most correct way to handle this situation is **pivot the data in the client code or reporting tool**. That is, return a result set from the SQL database looking more like this:

```
User   |   Date     | Value
 ABC   | 2021-02-12 |  0
 ABC   | 2021-02-12 |  2
 ABC   | 2021-02-10 |  0 
 ABC   | 2021-02-09 |  0
 ABC   | 2021-02-08 |  0
 ABC   | 2021-02-07 |  0
 XYZ   | 2021-02-12 |  0
 XYZ   | 2021-02-12 |  0
 XYZ   | 2021-02-10 |  0 
 XYZ   | 2021-02-09 |  0
 XYZ   | 2021-02-08 |  0
 XYZ   | 2021-02-07 |  0
... and so on
```

And then let the client do the work to reformat this data however you want, rather than asking a server that is often licensed at thousands of dollars per cpu core and isn't suited for the task to do that work.

But if you *really must* do this on the database server, you should know **the SQL language has a very strict requirement** to know the number, name, and type of columns in the output at query evaluation time, before looking at any data. Even `SELECT *` respects this, because the `*` is based on a table definition known ahead of time.

If the output won't know how many columns there are until it looks at the data,  you must do this in 3 steps:

1. Run a query to get data about columns.
2. Use the result from step 1 to build a new query dynamically.
3. Run the new query.

However, since it looks like you always want exactly 30 days worth of data, you *may* be able to do this in a single query using [the `PIVOT` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) if you're willing to name the columns something more like `OneDayBack`, `TwoDaysBack`, `ThreeDaysBack`, ... `ThirtyDaysBack`, such that you can reference them in the pivot code regardless of the current date.